# package com.facebook.react does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, node-modules, hybrid-mobile-app

This error showing in android only. ios working fine. Aprox 25 module showing this error. i have tried delete *.iml, .idea folders, delete nodemodules,invalid catch and restrart, everything.

React native: 0.59.9
Android studio : chipmunk, bumblebee, some other also,
OS : Mac mini M1 chip, (Ubuntu, windows tried also)

changes os, invalid crash and restart, Android studio versions

Comment: Maybe comes from this new error https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: @P-A You're my hero!

Comment: May I ask how you fixed this exactly? I'm on RN 0.61.5 and the instructions in the link provided don't change anything for me.

Comment: @skizzo just put mentioned code in android/buld.gradle file